# API calls blocks UI thread Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, core-data

I need to sync web database in my coredata, for which I perform service api calls. I am using `Alamofire` with `Swift 3`. There are 23 api calls, giving nearly 24k rows in different coredata entities.

**My problem:** These api calls blocks UI for a minute, which is a long time for a user to wait.

I tried using `DispatchQueue` and performing the task in background thread, though nothing worked. This is how I tried :

```
 let dataQueue = DispatchQueue.init(label: "com.app.dataSyncQueue")
 dataQueue.async {
        DataSyncController().performStateSyncAPICall()
        DataSyncController().performRegionSyncAPICall()
        DataSyncController().performStateRegionSyncAPICall()
        DataSyncController().performBuildingRegionSyncAPICall()

        PriceSyncController().performBasicPriceSyncAPICall()
        PriceSyncController().performHeightCostSyncAPICall()

        // Apis which will be used in later screens are called in background
        self.performSelector(inBackground: #selector(self.performBackgroundTask), with: nil) 

    }
```

**An API call from DataSyncController:**

```
 func performStateSyncAPICall() -> Void {
        DataSyncRequestManager.fetchStatesDataWithCompletionBlock {
            success, response, error in
            self.apiManager.didStatesApiComplete = true 
        }
    }
```

**DataSyncRequestManager Code:**

```
static func fetchStatesDataWithCompletionBlock(block:@escaping requestCompletionBlock) {

    if appDelegate.isNetworkAvailable {

        Util.setAPIStatus(key: kStateApiStatus, with: kInProgress)

        DataSyncingInterface().performStateSyncingWith(request:DataSyncRequest().createStateSyncingRequest() , withCompletionBlock: block)
    } else {
        //TODO: show network failure error
    }
}
```

**DataSyncingInterface Code:**

```
func performStateSyncingWith(request:Request, withCompletionBlock block:@escaping requestCompletionBlock)
 {
    self.interfaceBlock = block
    let apiurl = NetworkHttpClient.getBaseUrl() + request.urlPath!
     Alamofire.request(apiurl, parameters: request.getParams(), encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

             guard response.result.isSuccess else {
               block(false, "error", nil )
               return
             }

            guard  let responseValue = response.result.value else {
                block (false, "error", nil)
                return
            }
            block(true, responseValue, nil)
        }
}
```

I know many similar questions have been already posted on Stackoverflow and mostly it is suggested to use GCD or Operation Queue, though trying `DispatchQueues` didn't work for me.

Am I doing something wrong?
How can I not block UI and perform the api calls simultaneously?

Comment: Change DatasyncController(). to DatasyncController.

Comment: @Mozahler if you are suggesting to create a static function or to a variable for calling the functions none of them affects the performance, though I will make the functions as static ones.

Comment: Yes I was trying to be helpful because I couldn't be sure about the code you are calling but you didn't show us.

Comment: Also, I believe you have only added one unit of work to the queue.  If you add to the queue once per performXXX() they can be processed concurrently. You are looking for concurrency.

Comment: @Mozahler didn't get you. Can you explain again? Are you telling to create multiple queues ?

Comment: No. You create one queue, but you add to it one at a time. So:  dataQueue.async {
        DataSyncController().performStateSyncAPICall() }, then  dataQueue.async {
        DataSyncController(). performRegionSyncAPICall l() }... each of these can be queued, and on the same queue, but can now run independently of each other. I usually set queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 3 so that a maximum of 3 units of work are processing at once, but you may need a higher number. You really have only put one item into the queue.

Comment: Got it. Let me try!

Answer (score 6):

You can do this to run on a background thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

    // Do any processing you want.

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Go back to the main thread to update the UI.
    }
}
```

Comment: It still blocks UI.

Comment: That will put the work onto the background thread but that's not to say something inside the rest of the code is not then calling back to the main thread or blocking the main thread in some other way.  You would need to show the rest of the code for us to determine that.

Comment: I have updated my question with code samples. Let me know what can be wrong.

Comment: Can't see anything obvious.  Does the setAPIStatus method update the UI which might cause a slight problem.  In what way is the UI blocked?  Can you not do anything with it at all or some part specific?

Comment: setAPIStatus just stores data in UserDefaults. I am not doing anything which can block UI. I am redirected to a screen which has a `UITableView`, but neither scrolls works nor `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Prior to applying your changes, I wasn't even redirected to this new screen.

Comment: So at least my suggestion allowed part of the UI to continue.  How is the table view populated?  Is it based on the data the background thread is providing?  In which case how is the table view being reloaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146256/discussion-between-priyal-and-upholderoftruth).

Answer (score 0):

DispatchQueue manages the execution of work items. Each work item submitted to a queue is processed on a pool of threads managed by the system.

I usually use NSOperationQueue with Alamofire, but the concepts are similar.  When you set up an async queue, you allow work to be performed independently of the main (UI) thread, so that your app doesn't freeze (refuse user input).  The work will still take however long it takes, but your program doesn't block while waiting to finish.

You really have only put one item into the queue.

You are adding to the queue only once, so all those "perform" calls wait for the previous one to finish.  If it is safe to run them concurrently, you need to add each of them to the queue separately. There's more than one way to do this, but the bottom line is each time you call .async {} you are adding one item to the queue.

```
dataQueue.async { 
   DataSyncController().performStateSyncAPICall() 
}

dataQueue.async { 
   DataSyncController(). performRegionSyncAPICall l() 
}
```

Comment: I am not able to set maxConcurrentOperationCount. I am using DispatchQueue not operation queue.  Without operation count, it still blocks the UI.

Comment: Yes. I wasn't suggesting that would work for DispatchQueue. Now that I have looked at how I do it with Alamofire, I  see I have used Operation objects, and there a number of classes involved, so I don't recommend you adopt my approach.  Should I delete this answer? @UpholderOfTruth is right. The reason for your problem isn't in the code you have shown.